# sorting dates in key of tuples in dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, dictionary, calendar

I have a dictionary with entries that are of the format

`a = dict({(2,2013):[], (2,2011):[], (7,2013):[] , (4,2013):[]})`

i want my output to be like this:

`{(2,2011):[], (2,2013):[], (4,2013):[] , (7,2013):[]}`

By the way its supposed to be (month,year), how can i achieve that?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered in Python. If it does matter to you that they're ordered, you could use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). If you just want to print it out in a way that's easier to read, you could do `sorted(a.items())`

Comment: Could you explain a little why you want it to be ordered? Do you just want it to be displayed like that? Or do you need them to be ordered for some other calculation?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Grr edited comments. ;)

Comment: @Michael0x2a i this values as my (month,year)  so i need to make sure they are ordered for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of trying i changed my approach and instead of tuples, i used datetime objects and then applied the:

> months_sorted = sorted(months.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
myDict = {1: 1, 2: 2, 4:4, 2:1}
sorted_myDict = sorted(myDict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

sorted_myDict  will be a list of tuples sorted by the second element in each tuple.

@Decency answer is also very good option.

Comment: but it will only order my second elements (years) what about the first element(months)? i need something that does it for both

Comment: `iteritems()` returns a iterator of key-value tuples, so `operator.itemgetter(1))` accesses the first item (i.e., the key, which is itself the month-year tuple) from each element of the iterator.

Comment: after i get the tuple i do a dict(sorted_mydict) again, and when i do that this is what i get before: (4, 2013)
(2, 2013)
(7, 2013)
(6, 2013)
(3, 2013)
(11, 2012)
(9, 2012)
(5, 2013)
(9, 2013)
(8, 2013)
(8, 2012)
(1, 2013)
(10, 2013)
(12, 2012)
(10, 2012)

And after:

(4, 2013)
(2, 2013)
(12, 2012)
(6, 2013)
(8, 2012)
(11, 2012)
(9, 2012)
(10, 2012)
(9, 2013)
(8, 2013)
(3, 2013)
(1, 2013)
(10, 2013)
(7, 2013)
(5, 2013)

Comment: @psychok7 Again, dictionaries are unordered in Python. If you put the data back into a dictionary, it will not be ordered. sorted_myDict in this example is a list, not a dict. You can sort the data into a list as above, then add the data (from that list) to an OrderedDict in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain order for some reason, you can use an OrderedDict object.

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

Docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

```
class collections.OrderedDict([items])
```

Comment: this probably wont work for me because the order when inserting is not correct also.